# AppleScript to save current Safari window in webarchive format?

Tags: safari, applescript

**Without using GUI scripting**, how can I use AppleScript to tell **Safari** to save the current browser page to a file in webarchive format?  The following produces an error `"The document “...” could not be exported as “foo.webarchive”` (where "..." is the title of the current web page, whatever it may be):

```
set the_filepath to "/tmp/foo.webarchive"
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    save document 1 in the_filepath
end tell
```

I've tried variations on this, such as different file name extensions (e.g., `.html`) to see if anything works, but an error always arises. I've tried different ways of specifying the file name, but that also produces errors (of a different kind).  I've tried using `save ... as ".webarchive"` instead of the simple `save` above, but that produces a different error about "document 1 doesn't understand the save message".

The AppleScript dictionary for Safari 11 has this description:

```
save v : Save a document.
  save specifier : The document(s) or window(s) to save.
    [in file] : The file in which to save the document.
    [as saveable file format] : The file format to use.
```

This implies that it should be possible to save the current web page in a specific format understood by Safari (such as, hopefully, webarchive), and that I simply haven't figured out the right syntax.

Comment: If you can't find a way other then through UI Scripting, here's a nice example of it. [AppleScript: Safari - Save As Web Archive](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3343718?tstart=0)

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm trying to automate a more complicated workflow, and need to control things like where it writes the file. The AppleScript dictionary for Safari implies that `save` should accept an "as _format_" argument, so I keep hoping that it really can work and that I just haven't figured out the right syntax.

Comment: Have you tried variations such as `"webarchive"` and `"Web Archive"`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes; as soon as I add `as "formatname"` (whatever "formatname" I try), AppleScript Editor reports `error "Safari got an error: document 1 doesn’t understand the “save” message." number -1708 from document 1`.

Comment: @mhucka I had the same issue.. I posted a bundled script including newzelandpaul's webarchiver command that achieves the intended behavior.

Comment: I think Safari's AppleScript `save` command is broken. I tried a bare `save document 1`. While it did bring up the save dialog box, it appended .css to the document name instead of .webarchive. Even though the the format option at the bottom of the box was "Web Archive". Then when I hit save, I got the same error of "could not be exported" and error code 10000 (Apple Event Handler Failed). Moreover, after running the script, the Format dropdown menu in the save dialog box disappeared

Comment: If you're up for buying a potential solution, DevonThink can be scripted to create a webarchive. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to sign into a page yet. I'm going to try more tomorrow or Wednesday.

Comment: @Bruce Thanks for your efforts! I actually have DEVONthink Pro and use it constantly. The reason I'm asking the question is I'm trying to deal with paywalled websites. I need Safari to be the program that creates the archive because it's the program that has the session cookies.

Comment: @mhucka I was actually able to sign into a paywalled site within DEVONthink by using the helper page from [this post on their blog](http://blog.devontechnologies.com/2008/08/tuesday-tip-using-devonthink-pro-as-a-web-browser/). However, it does not seem that DEVONthink uses the cookies from that browsing session when it creates the webarchive.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a bundled script that saves the current tab to the desktop as a webarchive. Credit to [newzealandpaul](https://github.com/newzealandpaul) for his [webarchiver](https://github.com/newzealandpaul/webarchiver) shell command that powers this script. You can tweak the code to fit your specific needs, but this should do what that code in your question is trying to do.

Here is the bundled script: [SaveWebarchive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o9InCE0EKh8-QXwWLLTUbGosaTi7_YVv/view?usp=sharing)

This works with the [webarchiver](https://github.com/newzealandpaul/webarchiver) command bundled;

```
set fileName to "foo"

tell application "Safari" to set targetURL to (URL of document 1) as string
set commandPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "webarchiver.command")
do shell script "" & commandPath & " -url " & targetURL & " -output ~/Desktop/" & fileName & ".webarchive"
```

Note that the downloaded script may have the Script Editor interface showing the Log over the entire window.

Comment: So I download the source code for `webarchiver` and go to build it and find I had already done it before in September. I prefer to read the source code and build the executable vs. a pre-built executable when I don't really know the source. Anyway, I have to admit after reading the OP I focussed on using the `save` command and had forgotten about `webarchiver`. It works really nice and while it's not my question I'll still give a +1 for the answer!

Comment: I understand that you would want to compile it yourself! Just be sure to add `.command` to the end of the file and put it in the same location as the one I provided.

Comment: It actually shouldn't need the .command extension so long as `webarchiver` is set as executable. Haven't test it in AppleScript because I used it back in Sept from Terminal in a bash script just as `webarchiver` and that's how I know it works nice.

Comment: Okay. If that works for you, then that sounds great! I have tested the bundled script that I included, but if you can use `webarchiver` in an  even better way I'd love to hear how you do it!

Comment: It wasn't anything special per se, I just had a bunch of URLs in a file and used is as in the example at the authors GitHub project page, e.g. `webarchiver -url http://www.google.com -output google.webarchive`, but tokenized the command so when the script read the file it looped through the URLs. Just really basic stuff. I had forgotten all about it until you posted your answer to muck's question.

Comment: Thanks ... but this is not an answer to my question :-(. I specifically need to get Safari to do the saving. I know about `webarchiver` (and am using it already), but it cannot deal with paywalled web pages. When it executes, `webarchiver` runs as a separate process and does not have cookies or other things from my current Safari session. Thus, page blocks are in effect. Anyway, the bottom line is, my quest is to get Safari to do the saving :-).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. You're welcome to use the bundled script I included, but I'm not certain how to make Safari save the document with cookies..